# Why order is not maintained while reading a text file from Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Below is my Powershell script:

```
$server_file = 'serverlist.txt'
$servers = @{}
Get-Content $server_file | foreach-object -process {$current = $_.split(":"); $servers.add($current[0].trim(), $current[1].trim())}
foreach($server in $servers.keys){
    write-host "Deploying $service on $server..." -foregroundcolor green
}
```

My `serverlist.txt` looks like this:

```
DRAKE : x64
SDT: x64
IMPERIUS : x64
Vwebservice2012 : x64
```

Every time I run this script, I get `IMPERIUS` as my server name. I would like loop through the servers in the order they are written in `serverlist.txt`.
Am I missing anything in `Get-Content` call?

Comment: You're creating a hashtable - `@{}` - which by definition is not ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store servers in a temporary variable.

The iteration order of [hashtables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx) (`@{}`) is not guaranteed by the .NET framework. Avoid using them if you want to maintain input order.

Simply do:

```
$server_file = 'serverlist.txt'

Get-Content $server_file | ForEach-Object {
    $current = $_.split(":")
    $server = $current[0].trim()
    $architecture = $current[1].trim()

    Write-Host "Deploying $service on $server..." -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Note: Even if it probably won't make much of a difference in this particular case, in general you always should explicitly define the file encoding when you use `Get-Content` to avoid garbled data. `Get-Content` does not have sophisticated auto-detection for file encodings, and the default it uses can always be wrong for your input file.